# Identity Roles not being populated

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, identity

I have a simple sandbox project I'm using to get to better understand how .net Core Identity works and I've come across a bit of an inconsistency that I hope someone can explain.  This project is using Entity Framework.

I used this *awesome* article to help me set up the project, https://medium.com/@goodealsnow/asp-net-core-identity-3-0-6018fc151b4#.2env44446 and my User class is as follows.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TempPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I seeded the db with three users and three roles, one user for each role, "Owner", "Admin", and "User".  I added some policies for my actions,

```
auth.AddPolicy("Owner", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    policy.RequireRole("Owner");
 });

 auth.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
 {
     policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
     policy.RequireRole("Admin", "Owner");
 });

 auth.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
 {
     policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
 });
```

so my attributes like `[Authorize("Admin")]` work great.  I even added some principal extensions as so

```
public static class PrincipalExtensions
{
    public static bool IsOwner(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal.IsInRole("Owner");
    }

    public static bool IsAdmin(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal.IsInRole("Admin") || principal.IsInRole("Owner");
    }

    public static bool IsUser(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

so I can do `if(User.IsAdmin())` and this works perfectly as well.

Here is where it gets weird...

If I step through the following code I get confusing results.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);            
var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Owner");
```

The first line gets me a `User` object for the principal.  On that object there is a collection of his Roles, `user.Roles`, but it will show empty (Count = 0) even though the user *does* have roles.

The second line gets the `Roles` for the user and it populates correctly.

The third line adds the "Owner" role to the user and it works correctly (the db is updated) but also, the local variable `user` suddenly now has that role in `user.Roles`!  Note, none of the user's other roles will show up, just that one.

So I have basically two questions:  1.  Why doesn't the `user` object have the `user.Roles` populated to begin with?  2.  Why is it suddenly synced after I add a role?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Roles` collection isn't populated after calling `GetUserAsync()` as the [EntityFramework Identity UserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/2d157783465505bd0d36480ebe2e595543faff34/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs#L408) doesn't request the information. It's doing the equivalent of you accessing the user data directly through your `DbContext` and without any calls to `Include()`.

Right now [EF Core does not support lazy loading](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap), and therefore the `user.Roles` navigation property isn't automatically populated. And yes, this makes the behaviour somewhat disingenuous at the moment.

In your calls to `GetRolesAsync()` and `AddToRoleAsync()` the data is being explicitly populated for you, as you are operating on the roles directly.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  At first I was simply going to say "why would they put it on the object if they weren't going to populate it" but in the backlog section of that page it says it will be coming.

Comment: Heh, best of all, `user.Roles` is read-only so I can't even populate it myself!